# Writing a conditional in a compact way

Tags: conditionals

Could I write the if condition on the same line.  Is there any other way to include the equivalent of the `if` conditional in a more compact way ?

```
 (pcase grapheme
    ("dinkus"  
       (if (equal var "this")
           (insert "this")
         (insert "that"))))
```

Comment: Welcome!  Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: `(insert (if (equal var "this") "this" "that"))`

or

`(insert (or (and (equal var "this") "this") "that"))` Sometimes one uses the `and`-`or`-construct when the expression returns something.

Comment: Based on the last question, I'm guessing you're using a `pcase` statement with dozens of possible choices to insert either a latex character or a greek UTF-8 character. If I'm right about this, then this is the wrong question to ask. Help us by telling us the _real_ problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Trevoke: "*If I'm right about this, then this is the wrong question to ask.*" -- IMHO, we could answer the question even if it's *wrong*. Following this principle, we don't need to worry about whether the question is wrong or not -- If it's not wrong, that's good; if it's wrong, we can still answer it, and OP (and perhaps other readers) can still learn something, which is *also good*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just make these things functions and call the functions. That's how all programming works. You put multiple lines of code in one line of code by wrapping the multiple lines of code into a function.

Answer (score 2):

Only to show that this could be a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/232422) (TLDR: If we knew better what you want to do we could give you better help.):

If you are testing `var` in each of the `pcase` cases you could include that variable in the `pcase`-conditions:

```el
(pcase (list grapheme var)
    ('("dinkus" "this")  
     "this value")  
    (`("dinkus" ,_)  
     "that value"))
```

**Disclaimer:** I actually wanted to write this text as a comment. But, that comment turned out to be unreadable because of the missing newlines in the code. So I ended up writing an answer. But, maybe it is even acceptable as one of the possible answers.